# How to make Bayesian hyperparameter optimization reproducible using "mbo" tuner?

Tags: r, bayesian, hyperparameters, mlr3

I would like to use R's **mlr3*** packages to build ML algos in a reproducible manner. I have tried to use **regr.glmboost** learner with **mbo** tuner and **run_time** terminator. I have played around with the HPO part but I have not been able to make it reproducible with higher runtimes. Where did I go wrong?

Here is reprex about the phenomenon:

```
library(mlr3verse)
library(mlr3mbo)
library(mlr3misc)
library(magrittr)
library(nycflights13)

dt <- as.data.table(weather)
dt <- dt[order(time_hour), .(origin = as.factor(origin), month = as.factor(month), hour = as.factor(hour), temp, dewp, humid, wind_dir, wind_speed, precip, visib, pressure, time_hour = as.numeric(time_hour))]
dt <- na.omit(dt)

best_ones <- map_dtr(
  1L:3L,
  function(i) {
    my_learner <- lrn("regr.glmboost",
      family = to_tune(p_fct(levels = c("Gaussian", "Laplace", "Huber"))),
      nuirange = to_tune(p_dbl(lower = 0, upper = 1000, logscale = FALSE)),
      mstop = to_tune(p_int(lower = 1, upper = 3, trafo = function(x) 10**x)),
      nu = to_tune(p_dbl(lower = 0.01, upper = 0.3, logscale = TRUE)),
      risk = to_tune(p_fct(levels = c("inbag", "oobag", "none"))),
      trace = to_tune(c(TRUE, FALSE)),
      stopintern = to_tune(c(TRUE, FALSE))
    )

    my_task <- as_task_regr(
      x = dt,
      target = "pressure",
      id = "weather_data"
    )

    my_instance <- ti(
      task = my_task,
      learner = my_learner,
      resampling = rsmp("cv", folds = 3),
      measure = msr("regr.mae"),
      terminator = trm("run_time", secs = 300)
    )

    my_tuner <- tnr("mbo")

    set.seed(1234L, kind = "L'Ecuyer-CMRG")
    my_tuner$optimize(my_instance)

    my_instance$archive$best()
  }
)

best_ones[]
```

These are the somewhat diverse hyperparameters what I have got:

| family | nuirange | mstop | nu | risk | trace | stopintern | regr.mae | warnings | errors | runtime_learners | uhash | timestamp | batch_nr | acq_ei | .already_evaluated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Huber | 841.3256 | 3 | -2.794395 | inbag | FALSE | FALSE | 5.090834 | 0 | 0 | 9.656 | 01cf38ab-3dc6-4490-b36e-1c14325e42ad | 2023-01-10 17:08:15 | 26 | 0.0010821 | FALSE |
| Huber | 849.4117 | 3 | -2.774291 | oobag | FALSE | FALSE | 5.094204 | 0 | 0 | 9.646 | 6579c965-9184-4fe3-8e01-c1b10df21782 | 2023-01-10 17:11:56 | 18 | 0.0021940 | FALSE |
| Huber | 855.7414 | 3 | -2.878846 | oobag | FALSE | FALSE | 5.096876 | 0 | 0 | 9.497 | 458122cc-f51c-4d81-a6d2-93dc024baa58 | 2023-01-10 17:16:22 | 15 | 0.0090615 | FALSE |

I guess the issue is around seeding, but I do not know how to make it the proper way in this case. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I think there are two possible sources of error in your code:

1. I think the seed should be at the beginning of the function that is called in `map_dtr(...)` just to be sure.
2. I would not rely on the runtime terminator, as the different iterations might get more or less actual computation even though they have the same runtime. (You even see it in the output below, that all three repetitions have a slightly different runtime)

Addressing both seems to yield reproducible results (some of the code is slightly adjusted to keep the runtime lower).

I hope this also works for you.

```r
library(mlr3verse)
#> Loading required package: mlr3
library(mlr3mbo)
#> Loading required package: mlr3tuning
#> Loading required package: paradox
library(mlr3misc)
library(magrittr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'magrittr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:mlr3misc':
#> 
#>     set_class, set_names
library(nycflights13)

dt <- as.data.table(weather)
dt <- dt[order(time_hour), .(origin = as.factor(origin), month = as.factor(month), hour = as.factor(hour), temp, dewp, humid, wind_dir, wind_speed, precip, visib, pressure, time_hour = as.numeric(time_hour))]
dt <- na.omit(dt)

best_ones <- map_dtr(
  1L:3L,
  function(i) {
    set.seed(1234L, kind = "L'Ecuyer-CMRG")
    my_learner <- lrn("regr.glmboost",
      family = to_tune(p_fct(levels = c("Gaussian", "Laplace", "Huber"))),
      nuirange = to_tune(p_dbl(lower = 0, upper = 1000, logscale = FALSE)),
      mstop = to_tune(p_int(lower = 1, upper = 3, trafo = function(x) 10**x)),
      nu = to_tune(p_dbl(lower = 0.01, upper = 0.3, logscale = TRUE)),
      risk = to_tune(p_fct(levels = c("inbag", "oobag", "none"))),
      trace = to_tune(c(TRUE, FALSE)),
      stopintern = to_tune(c(TRUE, FALSE))
    )

    my_task <- as_task_regr(
      x = dt,
      target = "pressure",
      id = "weather_data"
    )

    my_instance <- ti(
      task = my_task,
      learner = my_learner,
      resampling = rsmp("holdout"),
      measure = msr("regr.mae"),
      terminator = trm("evals", n_evals = 2)
    )

    my_tuner <- tnr("mbo")

    my_tuner$optimize(my_instance)

    my_instance$archive$best()
  }
)
#> INFO  [22:33:53.565] [bbotk] Starting to optimize 7 parameter(s) with '<OptimizerMbo>' and '<TerminatorEvals> [n_evals=2, k=0]'
#> ... (A LOT OF LOG OUTPUT THAT IS OMITTED)

best_ones[]
#>    family nuirange mstop        nu risk trace stopintern regr.mae warnings
#> 1:  Huber 85.45087     3 -2.572761 none FALSE      FALSE  4.74076        0
#> 2:  Huber 85.45087     3 -2.572761 none FALSE      FALSE  4.74076        0
#> 3:  Huber 85.45087     3 -2.572761 none FALSE      FALSE  4.74076        0
#>    errors runtime_learners                                uhash  x_domain
#> 1:      0            3.406 653adf83-6fbc-4ef5-b6dd-7e12e97b49d6 <list[7]>
#> 2:      0            3.773 f70dec6a-073a-45c8-b795-29ef5b662625 <list[7]>
#> 3:      0            3.673 dc18e13f-2e7d-4fe9-9845-187ebf0db3b3 <list[7]>
#>              timestamp batch_nr
#> 1: 2023-01-10 22:34:17        1
#> 2: 2023-01-10 22:34:41        1
#> 3: 2023-01-10 22:35:05        1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Ok, I have understood that "run_time" terminator is not about reproducibility. Thank you for your help! Nonetheless I have just tried the iteration with the relocated seeding and the "run_time" terminator remained as it was originally and it has given stable results. So it became **seemingly** reproducible.

Answer (score 3):

One more comment on why the seed should got to the top here:

HPO is essentially noisy black box optimization with noise mainly due to:

1. the learner algorithm being non-deterministic
2. the objective, i.e., generalization error being estimated via a resampling method

To reduce the noise during optimization, we can fix the resampling, i.e., `instantiate` it on the `Task` (and therefore use the same train test splits for the evaluation of hyperparameter configurations).

When you are constructing the `TuningInstance`:

```
my_instance <- ti(
  task = my_task,
  learner = my_learner,
  resampling = rsmp("cv", folds = 3),
  measure = msr("regr.mae"),
  terminator = trm("run_time", secs = 300)
)
```

you are passing a `Resampling` that has (yet) not been instantiated on the `Task`. However, during construction of the `ObjectiveTuning` within the constructing of the `TuningInstance` it will automatically be instantiated (to make the optimization less noisy and 'easier').

Therefore, if you do not seed the construction of `my_instance`, the train test splits based on the CV folds will be different and you naturally obtain different optimizer runs and results.

Essentially, what you observed in your non-reproducible example is the effect of the noise due to different resampling!

One final note:
If your `Objective` is noisy, `mlr3mbo` will by default determine the result of the tuning by choosing the configuration with the best surrogate model mean prediction that is, `my_instance$result` will have been obtained by making use of `result_by_surrogate_design` instead of `result_by_default` (which is the same as using `my_instance$archive$best()`).

Therefore be careful in using `my_instance$result` vs. `my_instance$archive$best()` but this also comes down to your user preference and what you are interested in.